# Loading jQuery gallery after the Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to put a jQuery gallery after the Ajax call. On my main site, I create a div which wrap the main content (e.g site_content). When users click on one of the hyperlink on the main page, the "site_content" will get updated and display other content which is saved at other HTML file and I am using AJAX to avoid the whole page refresh. However I  having a problem of running the JavaScript/jQuery gallery because the JavaScript won't work after the AJAX call.

I understand that because the browser does not know there will be some functions to call after the content (from the other HTML file) is successfully displayed. I tried to use the jQuery getScript method but it is still not working.

Could anyone give me some ideas how can I run the javaScript/jQuery gallery after the AJAX call?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such circumstances you need to keep jQuery [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) and [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function in mind.

Just go through the tutorial try on to your ajax call and see the magic.

For eg.

```
var hurray = function(data) {
  do_stuff(data)
}

$(".example").ajax({
  'success': hurray
})
```